# Custom UITabBar unselected item's color

Tags: swift, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I am trying to change the default grey colour of the unselected UITabBarItems. I have managed to change the text but not the image.

[image]

```
TabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 86.0/255.0, green: 132.0/255.0, blue: 208.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

var normalTint: UIColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

TabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: normalTint,NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 13)!], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**you can use** `.AlwaysOriginal`

```
tabBarItem.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "first-selected")!.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
```

Answer (score 15):

iOS 10 | Swift 3

```
class TabBarVC: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // make unselected icons white
        self.tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.white
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, great. Didn't checked the iOS10 documentation.

Answer (score 3):

- If you want to set unselected icons to specific color through Storyboard.
- You can do it through 'User defined runtime attributes', without adding the codes.
  [image]

Comment: I used this and receive this error in iOS 9 : this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key unselectedItemTintColor.\

Answer (score 0):

```html
func styleTabBar(){
    let fontAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.gray, NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10.0)]
    let selectedFontAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red, NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10.0)]
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        let tabBarAppearance = UITabBarAppearance()
        let tabBarItemAppearance = UITabBarItemAppearance()
        tabBarItemAppearance.normal.iconColor = UIColor.gray
        tabBarItemAppearance.selected.iconColor = UIColor.red
        tabBarItemAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = fontAttributes
        tabBarItemAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = selectedFontAttributes
        
        tabBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        tabBarAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        tabBarAppearance.stackedLayoutAppearance = tabBarItemAppearance
        UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance = tabBarAppearance
        if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
            UITabBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = tabBarAppearance
        }
    }else{
        UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.white
        UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.gray
        UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.red
     UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(fontAttributes, for: .normal)
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(selectedFontAttributes, for: .selected)
    }

}
```