# change tab bar non selected icon color swift

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have tab bar and I want to change icons color from default gray to white,
I added this line in AppDelegate

```
UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red:0.51, green:0.39, blue:0.37, alpha:1.0)
```

this is change `selected` item, How I acn do that with non selected?

Comment: If you are setting image to tab bar check this once http://stackoverflow.com/a/38560183/6433023

Comment: Possible duplicate of these similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30754026 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29876722

Answer (score 2):

For Swift use below:

```
self.tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.white
```

Comment: iOS 15 is not supported

Answer (score 2):

Support for iOS 14 and iOS 15:

```
    if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
        let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()

        appearance.backgroundColor = bgColor
        appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.iconColor = unselectedColor
        appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: unselectedColor]

        tabBarAppearance.standardAppearance = appearance
        tabBarAppearance.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
    } else {
        tabBarAppearance.backgroundColor = bgColor
        tabBarAppearance.barTintColor = bgColor
        tabBarAppearance.unselectedItemTintColor = unselectedColor
    }
```

Comment: Great thank you, this worked for me in swiftUI too, whereas other solutions didn't.

Answer (score 1):

Change according to below code for Tab bar controller for change tab item 
selected and Deselected color.

```
class TabbarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.purpleColor()

        // set red as selected background color
        let numberOfItems = CGFloat(tabBar.items!.count)
        let tabBarItemSize = CGSize(width: tabBar.frame.width / numberOfItems, height: tabBar.frame.height)
        tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = UIImage.imageWithColor(UIColor.lightTextColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5), size: tabBarItemSize).resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsetsZero)

        // remove default border
        tabBar.frame.size.width = self.view.frame.width + 4
        tabBar.frame.origin.x = -2

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        // For Images
        let firstViewController:UIViewController = NotificationVC()
        // The following statement is what you need
        let customTabBarItem:UITabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "notification@2x")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "notification_sel@2x"))
        firstViewController.tabBarItem = customTabBarItem

        for item in self.tabBar.items! {
            let unselectedItem = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
            let selectedItem = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.purpleColor()]

            item.setTitleTextAttributes(unselectedItem, forState: .Normal)
            item.setTitleTextAttributes(selectedItem, forState: .Selected)
        }
    } 
}

extension UIImage {
    class func imageWithColor(color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        let rect: CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
        color.setFill()
        UIRectFill(rect)
        let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }

}
```

Comment: do you mean I have to ctreate new class called TabbarController?

Comment: Yes need to create class for access Tab bar controller and changes inside tab bar.

Comment: I got error in this line `let firstViewController:UIViewController = NotificationVC()`

Comment: You need to add your first tab bar controller name in place of  - NotificationVC()

Comment: this is the first view in tab bar is mainViewController(),I added but nothing happen :( have I add anything else or what?

Comment: I don't know man what exact r u doing need to add there your first view controller name only and this is working code.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have made your icons in the colour that you wanted them to be (in photoshop or sketch or whatever), you can do this via the attributes inspector.

Go to your storyboard, find your view controller (whcih should have been embedded in the tab bar controller already) and select the tab bar at the bottom of the view controller.

In the attributes inspector set the "Image" under Bar Item to your unselected tab bar item image (which should be in your assets already) and set the "Selected Image" under Tab Bar Item to your selected version.

Next, go to your asset catalogue, select your image and in the attributes inspector, under Image Set, set the Render As to Original Image. Do this for all your icons.

This should now work